# iOS: failed socket-flow with Spring Boot

Tags: ios, xcode, spring, heroku, alamofire

**Background**
I want to send a base64 string from an iOS app to a Spring boot backend using the Alamofire lib.

**Problem**
It fails with this error:

```
2017-08-31 10:22:49.547259+0200 Epic[851:367066] [] 
nw_endpoint_flow_prepare_output_frames [6.1 46.30.215.94:80 ready 
socket-flow (satisfied)] Failed to use 1 frames, marking as failed
2017-08-31 10:22:49.549173+0200 Epic[851:367066] [] 
nw_endpoint_handler_add_write_request [6.1 46.30.215.94:80 failed 
socket-flow (satisfied)] cannot accept write requests
2017-08-31 10:22:49.552773+0200 Epic[851:367069] [] 
tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received 
error: [22] Invalid argument
```

This problem occured when I changed endpoint from my local development environment to Heroko. (http://heroku.com).

I can send smaller images without problem (100x100) but not (600x600).

**I have tried:**
-To add a http header "Content-Length" and length of the json body.
-To change from sending a json body to URL params.

Any suggestions? Can I configure heroku spring boot to accept bigger http requests of data or is it a setting a need to do in the app?

My code:

```
func createImage(_ image: UIImage, success: @escaping (String)->(), failed: @escaping (Void)->(Void)){
    let base64 = image.getImageAsBase64()
    Alamofire.request(self.url, method: .put, parameters: ["image" : base64], headers: self.headers)
        .responseString(completionHandler: {response in
            switch(response.result) {
            case .success(let response):
                success(response)
                break;
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                failed()
                break;
            }
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. It's because the character amount of Alamofire.request ist limited. You need to use Alamofire.upload for images or large data. See https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#uploading-data-to-a-server.